# Error al ejecutar el comando ng serve

Tags: angular, angularjs

Tengo este error al ejecutar el comando ng serve en mi proyecto de angular..les agradezco su ayuda de antemano

Error: node_modules/ngx-barcode6/lib/ngx-barcode6.component.d.ts:33:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

33     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgxBarcode6Component, "ngx-barcode6", never, { "elementType": { "alias": "bc-element-type"; "required": false; }; "cssClass": { "alias": "bc-class"; "required": false; }; "format": { "alias": "bc-format"; "required": false; }; "lineColor": { "alias": "bc-line-color"; "required": false; }; "width": { "alias": "bc-width"; "required": false; }; "height": { "alias": "bc-height"; "required": false; }; "displayValue": { "alias": "bc-display-value"; "required": false; }; "fontOptions": { "alias": "bc-font-options"; "required": false; }; "font": { "alias": "bc-font"; "required": false; }; "textAlign": { "alias": "bc-text-align"; "required": false; }; "textPosition": { "alias": "bc-text-position"; "required": false; }; "textMargin": { "alias": "bc-text-margin"; "required": false; }; "fontSize": { "alias": "bc-font-size"; "required": false; }; "background": { "alias": "bc-background"; "required": false; }; "margin": { "alias": "bc-margin"; "required": false; }; "marginTop": { "alias": "bc-margin-top"; "required": false; }; "marginBottom": { "alias": "bc-margin-bottom"; "required": false; }; "marginLeft": { "alias": "bc-margin-left"; "required": false; }; "marginRight": { "alias": "bc-margin-right"; "required": false; }; "value": { "alias": "bc-value"; "required": false; }; "valid": { "alias": "bc-valid"; "required": false; }; }, {}, never, never, false, never>;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

✖ Failed to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error se debe a que estas usando un librería que necesita una versión de angular inferior a la que estas ejecutando, para solucionarlo puedes hacer un downgrade de la versión de angular para usar la que necesite la librería o en el caso de que dispongas de una versión mas actualizada de la librería deberías actualizarla a esta versión.